# function return type from assignement

Tags: julia

Here I expected Int type but got Float:

```
julia> function test()
         i::Int = 3.0
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> typeof(test())
Float64
```

and in this case return type is Int:

```
julia> function test()
         i::Int = 3.0
         i
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> typeof(test())
Int64
```

Is this correct behavior or bug?

Comment: a gotcha but not a bug. Great example of why explicit return statements are usually a good idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quote from Jeff:

> [`=` returns the right-hand side every time. No exceptions.](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7341#issuecomment-46729127)

so in the first example, it's equivalent to directly return what `=` returns i.e. `3.0`:

```
julia> @code_lowered test()
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        SSAValue(0) = 3.0
        i = (Core.typeassert)((Base.convert)(Main.Int, SSAValue(0)), Main.Int)
        return SSAValue(0)
    end))
```